# How do I check if multiple values exists in database?

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee

I have a list of email addresses in the Java code and I would like to check if any of these already exists in the MySQL database.

For example:

1. `a@a.com`
2. `b@b.com`
3. `c@c.com`

I want to know if any of the above email ids is already present in the table, and if they do, I would like to  pull or separate them out.

I am not sure how to achieve this. Should I try this in Java or use SQL to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Here are different solutions that will help you achieve what you want

- This SQL expression will tell you if an email *exists* or *not*:

  ```sql
  SELECT IF (COUNT(*) > 0, 'Exist', 'Not exist')
  FROM email_table 
  WHERE email = 'a@a.com';
  ```
- If you just want the *number of occurrences* you can do this:

  ```sql
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM email_table
  WHERE email = 'a@a.com';
  ```
- If you want to check for *multiple values* at a time you can do this:

  ```sql
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM email_table
  WHERE email IN ('a@a.com', 'b@b.com');
  ```
- If you want to see which *IDs* are found:

  ```sql
  SELECT email
  FROM email_table
  WHERE email IN ('a@a.com', 'b@b.com');
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class EmailList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // collect output into this list
        List<String> existing = new ArrayList<String>();

        // load this list as you please, such as a file
        List<String> source = new ArrayList<String>();
        source.add("tom@hotmail.com");
        source.add("dick@hotmail.com");
        source.add("harry@hotmail.com");

        boolean noRowProcessed = true;
        String sql = "SELECT email FROM my_table WHERE email IN (";
        for(String email : source) {
            if(!noRowProcessed){
                sql += ", ";
            }
            sql += "'" + email + "'";
            noRowProcessed = false;
        }
        sql += ")";

        System.out.println(sql);


        // run your query here and collect output into list 'existing'
    }   
 }
```